# is it ok to use const_cast in member routines to avoid duplicated code

Tags: c++, oop, const-cast

Is it okay to use `const_cast` in the following case, or are there any caveats:

```
class A {
public:
  A() : m_someData(5) {}

  int& get() { return m_someData; }

  const int& get() const { return *const_cast<A*>(this)->get(); }
private:
  int m_someData;
};
```

The intention is that the `get` routine may be much more complicated and code duplication should be avoided.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. I wouldn't suggest that. I would suggest you to use `const_cast` in reverse direction:

```
int& get() { return const_cast<int&>(const_cast<A const &>(*this).get()); };

const int& get() const {  return m_someData; };
```

That is, you should call the *const* member function from *non-const* overload, not the other way round. That way, you ensure that even the non-const version doesn't change the state of the object and the code in both functions are indeed *same* (because you call the const version eventually) — and there *would be certainly code duplication* which you want to avoid.

If you do this the other way round, the compiler will not tell you if you modify the object in non-const version of the function and it would be incorrect to call such function from const function.

Comment: I don't think it matters which one calls the other one; either way, you have to be certain that neither of them does any modifications. When the const delegates to the non-const, you must ensure the non-const does no modifications. When the non-const delegates to the const, you must ensure the const does not return anything *actually* `const`. And with the const overload calling the non-const one, you at least save one `const_cast`.

Comment: @Angew: non-const version might modify the object. if you do so, the compiler will not tell you. so it is not safe to call the non-const function from const function.

Comment: @Angew i think he is right. if i cast the this to nonconst and call the non const get() then the compiler does not enforce that the this object is not changed in the get

Comment: If you do the work in the `const` overload, the compiler will hopefully stop most modifications because `*this` is `const`. If you do the work in the non-`const` overload you may accidentally invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: I think decision really concerns the programmer than the compiler. If the non-const version is as proposed in this answer, it's just one line and I can easily check the object is not modified. If the non-const version is the one that actually does the job and is say 10 lines long, it's easy to miss a point where state is modified. So I'd rather have the compiler do the checking for me.

Answer (score 2):

As user [@Nawaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415784/nawaz) has pointed out in their answer, it is better to `const_cast` the other way, which has less potential for making a mistake. This can be made slightly easier with [`std::as_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const):

```cpp
int& get() { return const_cast<int&>(std::as_const(*this).get()); }
```

However, many style guides ban `const_cast` ([e.g. CppCoreGuidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-casts-const)) for such purposes because it is difficult to tell whether what you're doing is correct at first glance. Consider the following alternatives.

#### Static member function template (C++98 - C++20)

```cpp
private:
  // C++20 abbreviated function template.
  // In C++17 and prior, use template <typename Self>
  // Implementable in C++98 (see comments), but much more verbose.
  static auto& get(auto &self) { return self.m_someData; }

public:
  int& get() { return get(*this); }

  const int& get() const { return get(*this); }
```

This solution works because `*this` will be either `A` or `const A` depending on non-static member function is calling the static member function template.
Many developers prefer this, because there is no `const_cast` at all, and so it is trivial to verify that this code is const-correct. However, `get` being a template may increase code size.

#### [Deducing this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#Explicit_object_parameter) (C++23)

With this C++23 feature, we can accept `this` as a function parameter and handle all combinations of cv-qualifiers and reference qualifiers in one function.
This is similar to the first solution, however, we only have to write a single function.

```cpp
// returns int&, const int&, volatile int&, or const volatile int&
auto& get(this auto &&self) { return self.m_someData; }
```

You could extend this further, so that when you have an `A` rvalue, you return `int&&`. For an `int`, this would be useless, but it may make sense for other types of members:

```cpp
// returns int&, const int&, volatile int&, const volatile int&,
//   int&&, const int&&, volatile int&&, or const volatile int&&
template <typename Self>
auto&& get(this Self &&self) { return std::forward<Self>(self).m_someData; }
```

Comment: have not seen `auto` in C++98  ;-) - i currently not see, how to replace the return type auto in pre-auto-compilers (to still get the auto-const-ness)
But nice - I just read about "Deducing this" a few days ago.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch you would have to implement a type trait equivalent to [`std::add_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_cv) in C++98. The return type would look something like: `typename add_const<typename Self::some_data_type>::type`.

Comment: Actually it would be a bit more complicated: `typename conditional<is_const<Self>::value, typename add_const<typename Self::some_data_type>::type, some_data_type>::type`. It would be simpler to use a `copy_cv_qual` trait which takes the cv qualifiers from one type and applies it to another: `typename copy_cv_qual<some_data_type, Self>::type`.

Comment: I hope, I never have to deal with pre c++17 compiler again 